# I'm always here for you - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

It is a love/hate relationship we share,
Sometimes great, sometimes you just stare.
Everyday, sometimes for hours you use me,
I try my best, so please don't abuse me.
I make life so easy, I make life so hard.
I can do almost anything, even make a card.
I am a newer friend, haven't been here too long.
Do you like music? I can sing you a song.
I often keep you from getting bored.
A lot I do requires a cord.
So while you figure out who I may be,
Just know it is often me that you see.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: +1 from me. I didn't think this was too easy actually; I certainly wouldn't have got the answer as quickly as @Shashank did!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to me the answer is

> Laptop

Sometimes great, sometimes you just stare.

> Sometimes you just stare at your laptop when you read or see something amazing.

Everyday, sometimes for hours you use me,
I try my best, so please don't abuse me.

> You use your laptop almost everyday and sometimes for many hours a day. so you should shut down your laptop once in a while and not abuse it.

I make life so easy, I make life so hard.
I can do almost anything, even make a card.

> laptop helps you connect to friends even those who are very far from you, but ruins your social life when you use your laptop way too much. you can use your laptop for a lot of things, including making cards.

Do you like music? I can sing you a song.
I often keep you from getting bored.
A lot I do requires a cord.

> Laptop keeps you from getting bored and can be used to play songs or movies, needs a charger to keep running.

Comment: More specific than I was going for (I was just looking for computer), but very nice!

Comment: I was thinking smartphone but the card thing doesn't really fit in my answer.